# Is there a $routechangesuccess or $viewcontentloaded event when ng-includes are loaded?

Tags: angularjs

I've tried

- $stateChangeSuccess,
- $routeChangeSuccess, and
- $viewContentLoaded

but I can't get my custom jQuery init function to run after my ng-include loads or if I switch it after the fact with an ng-swith.

*Index.html has ng-view to dashboard.html which has this code.*

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Switch Dashboard View: <input type="radio" name="dashboardView" value="0" ng-model="vm.dashboardView" />Franchisee | 
        <input type="radio" name="dashboardView" value="1" ng-model="vm.dashboardView" />Real Estate
    </div>
</div>
<!--tiles end-->
<div data-ng-switch="vm.dashboardView">
    <div data-ng-switch-when="0">
        <div data-ng-include="'/Views/Dashboard/FranchiseeDashboard.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-switch-when="1">
        <div data-ng-include="'/Views/Dashboard/RealestateDashboard.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*index.html has a controller which has this*

```
  $rootScope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function () {
        Interactions.init();

    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
       function (event, next, current) {
           Interactions.init();
       }
   );
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',
       function (event, next, current) {
           Interactions.init();
       }
   );
```

How can I get my jquery function to fire after ng-switch has loaded an ng-include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work $viewContentLoaded and includeContentLoaded
Look at the events for ngInclude 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude